# I have query and i want this to have pagination in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

```
    SELECT 
        a.*, b.* 
    FROM
        daily a, server b
    WHERE  
        to_date(a.insertdatetime) >= DATE '2020-03-17' 
        AND  to_date(a.insertdatetime) <= DATE '2020-03-18' 
        AND a.status LIKE '%ERROR%'   
        AND b.category LIKE '%BOOK%' 
   ORDER BY a.insertdatetime, b.place, b.name ;
```

How to make this query to have some pagination ?

Comment: `offset .. rows fetch first ... rows only`

Comment: I have add it but the offset just fetch from the rownum

Comment: Aside from your immediate question, your use of to_date() on INSERTDATETIME suggests that INSERTDATETIME is not a DATE data type.  If this is true, that is itself a design flaw. There is simply no excuse for storeing date/time in anything other than a DATE or some variant of TIMESTAMP.  No, if INSERTDATETIME _is_ a DATE, then you should not be appling to_date() to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what *you* call pagination.

From pure database perspective, assuming Oracle 12c, you can use the row limiting clause:

```
select d.*, s.* 
from daily d
inner join server s on d.domainurl = s.domainurl
where    
    d.insertdatetime >= DATE '2020-03-17' 
    d.insertdatetime <  DATE '2020-03-19' 
    and d.status   LIKE '%ERROR%'   
    and s.category LIKE '%BOOK%' 
order by d.insertdatetime, s.place, s.name 
offset <N> rows fetch next <M> rows
```

Where `N` (resp. `M`) represent how many rows should be skipped (resp. selected).

Side notes:

- always use modern, explicit join syntax rather than old-school, implicit joins
- avoid using functions in `where` predicates if you can
- meaningful table aliases make the query easier to wite and read